# Is there a way to search an unordered_set using a limited alphabetic range?

Tags: c++, string, search

Context: I am coding an assignment in C++ where a user enters a word or a sentence to unscramble on a word by word basis. I have a text file full of English words that I have read into an unordered_set of strings. Then I go through permutations of each entered word and attempt to find it in the unordered_set. The unscrambled word possibilities are printed out to the user.

Problem: There are a lot of words in the text file. The program doesn't run properly because it takes too long to go through all the permutations and look for a match in the unordered_set.

Possible Solution: I want to limit the range of words to search through, because the text file was already in alphabetical order. For example, if the scrambled word was "cit", one permutation for this word would be "itc". I want to search all of the words in the unordered_set starting with i for "itc".

Here is what I have so far.

```
void unscramble() {

    //issue - too slow, find in range?
    string word;
    string temp;
    ifstream inDictionaryFile("words_alpha.txt");
    unordered_set<string> dictionary;

    //read dictionary file into a unordered_set
    while (getline(inDictionaryFile, temp)) {
        auto result = dictionary.insert(temp + " ");
    }
    cout << "Enter something to unscramble: ";

    //find/print out matches for permuations of scrambled words
    while (cin>>word) {
        do {
            word = word + " ";
            auto result = dictionary.find(word);
            if (result != end(dictionary)) {
                cout << setw(10) << word;
            }
        } while (next_permutation(begin(word), end(word)));
    }


}
```

Comment: If you used an ordered set, a `std::set` if you will, then you can keep a `std::map<char, std::set::iterator>` that maps to the iterator of the first word in the set that starts with each letter.

Comment: Another possible optimization is to also check the length. If the scrambled word have three letters, then skip all words in the set that doesn't have three letters.

Comment: I don't see how your plan is going to help, but it looks like you've reduced the problem to the `unordered_set` being unordered, unlike the input data. So.... don't drop the ordering? Your changing needs have caused your choice of data structure to become undesirable.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the permutation of just the first 3 letters you may use an unordered_multiset with the key equal to a canonical permutation (e.g. the sorted first 3 letters). But I guess that the actual problem that you have should not be solved with just one data structure but with several ones, one data structure for storage, other data structures for  indexes to that storage.